# How to get MimeContent using GraphServiceClient Microsoft Graph API

Tags: c#, graph

I want to get MimeContent for an email using GraphServiceClient in Microsoft. Graph Ver 1.15.

I found we can get the mime content using:
HTTP
GET /users/{id}/messages/{id}/$value

But how can I translate this on a Request?

There is another way or another NuGet package to get this?

Answer (score 1):

```
Workaround to get mime content from message-id
```

```
 using (HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient())
            {                    
                httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

                Uri requestEndpoint = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages/{id}/$value");

                string mimeResponse = await httpclient.GetStringAsync(requestEndpoint);

                byte[] emailData= System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mimeResponse);

                Stream stream = new MemoryStream(emailData);
                //upload logic
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the lastest Microsoft.Graph package (currently in version 5.31.0.0) you can use this :

```
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(/*your authentication details*/);
var stream = await graphClient.Users[/*your account address*/].Messages[/*your message ID*/].Content.GetAsync();
//for a string content :
var mimeString = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
//for a parsed representation, use the fantastic MimeKit
var mimeMessage = MimeMessage.Load(messageStream);
```